# Magento 2 + Programatically create product issue

Tags: magento2, product, programmatically

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Xyz\Model\SampleData;

use Exception;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class CreateSimpleProduct
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * CreateSimpleProduct constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup    = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->logger             = $logger;
        $this->productFactory     = $productFactory;
        $this->productRepository  = $productRepository;
        $this->categoryFactory    = $categoryFactory;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->storeManager       = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function createSimpleProduct()
    {
        try {
            $product        = $this->productFactory->create();

            $simpleProductArray = [
                0 => [
                    'name'              => 'Simple Visible',
                    'sku'               => 'Simple Visible',
                    'price'             => 50,
                    'weight'            => 5,
                    'description'       => 'Product description text',
                    'short_description' => 'Short Description',
                    'website_ids'       => array(1),
                    'category_ids'      => array(4),
                    'type_id'           => Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
                    'visibility'        => Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
                    'status'            => Status::STATUS_ENABLED,
                    'url_key'           => 'simple-visible',
                    'meta_title'        => 'Simple Visible',
                    'meta_keyword'      => 'Simple Visible',
                    'meta_description'  => 'Simple Visible Product description text',
                ]
            ];

            foreach ($simpleProductArray as $data) {
                // Create Product
                $product = $this->productFactory->create();
                $product->setSku($data['sku'])
                    ->setName($data['name'])
                    ->setWeight($data['weight'])
                    ->setPrice($data['price'])
                    ->setDescription($data['description'])
                    ->setShortDescription($data['short_description'])
                    ->setWebsiteIds($data['website_ids'])
                    ->setCategoryIds($data['category_ids'])
                    ->setTypeId($data['type_id'])
                    ->setVisibility($data['visibility'])
                    ->setAttributeSetId($data['attribute_set_id'])
                    ->setStatus($data['status'])
                    ->setUrlKey($data['url_key'])
                    ->setMetaTitle($data['meta_title'])
                    ->setMetaKeyword($data['meta_keyword'])
                    ->setMetaDescription($data['meta_description'])
                    ->setStockData(
                        [
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                            'manage_stock'            => 1,
                            'is_in_stock'             => 1,
                            'qty'                     => 500
                        ]
                    );
                $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
                $product->save();
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my script to create a product programmatically its create product successfully, but issue what I found there is 2 entry of product attributes database for store 1 & 0.

I just need to create product global like when we create from admin and all entries for store 0.

Comment: i think this is because you are not setting store id. if you want to save for only storeid 0 then set store_id in product object.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh its not working i have checked with that.